# Need help to adjust row width and graph size for Horizontal Bar chart using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

Here's my code but I want to adjust the row width so the names are clear to read and adjust size of the graph. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
# Building the model 
extra_tree_forest = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators = 81, 
                                        criterion ='entropy', max_features = 5) 

# Training the model 
extra_tree_forest.fit(X, y) 

# Computing the importance of each feature 
feature_importance = extra_tree_forest.feature_importances_ 

# Normalizing the individual importances 
feature_importance_normalized = np.std([tree.feature_importances_ for tree in 
                                        extra_tree_forest.estimators_], 
                                        axis = 0) 

# Plotting a Bar Graph to compare the models 
plt.barh(X.columns, feature_importance_normalized) 
plt.xlabel('Feature Labels') 
plt.ylabel('Feature Importances') 
plt.title('Comparison of Different Feature Importances (Cluster1)') 
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [`ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', labelsize=8)`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to increase the dimensions of your figure. Add the following line at the top of your code

```
plt.figure(figsize=(<width>, <height>)) # dimensions are in inches
```

In you case, it would be sensible to choose a  that's proportional to the number of columns in your dataset